# Grub won't boot after patitioning Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

I partitioned my Windows 7 into two drives using Minitool Partition Wizard.  I also have a Ubuntu partition on the same computer.

After the partition was over, it restarted into the Grub rescue mode screen and won't allow me to boot into either OS. The error I'm getting says "Unknown filesystem". I don't have access to the Windows 7 disc since the software came preinstalled with my laptop.

What can I do? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use any Linux distribution - put it on USB or DVD.

Boot from Linux USB/DVD.

You have two choices:

1. Delete the new created partition (if there is nothing important on it else save files on it to USB - do not delete the Windows 7 partition !!

Reboot - you should be fine.

2. Use "Boot-repair" from Linux to fix booting (see "[boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)")

After you have fixed booting CREATE WINDOWS 7 RECOVERY USB/CD/DVD from within Windows 7 so you are prepared for future boot failures and don't have Linux installed on disk anymore.